# Outlook 365, emails with attachment not showing in search results

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Emails with attachment not shown in search result
Seems this problem start happening from June 2023. Emails with attachments before June 2023 can be searched normally.
I checked Indexing Options; status was Indexing complete. And I have rebuilt index again, problem still exist.
Please help fix this problem so that emails can be shown in search results normally.
I wanted to write more details with pictures but superuser said "Looks like spam".
Thanks.

Comment: What operating system?  Microsoft put out a number of products in 2013 and support is dropping now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Exchange Online as email service?
If yes, there has been a recent issue which may be related.

You can access Microsoft 365 admin center>Health>Service health and check for EX574075 (Some users may be unable to see messages with attachments when searching in Exchange Online) if you have admin access.

Screenshot:

[image: EX574075]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. In the layout settings, under message organization. I selected `Newest to top` and somehow this fixed the attachments not showing. I have no idea why but if it is on `Show Each Message Separately` it doesn't show attachments.

[image: Layout settings]